# How to select data from my controller with button click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a view that takes data from JSON, uses that data to populate a list of buttons (with basic information about the data) and then upon clicking the button, I want another panel to be populated with the data bound to the data in the button.

```
<div ng-controller="QueueCtrl">
    <ul class="list-unstyled" ng-repeat="ticket in tickets">
        <li><div data-queue-item></div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This part populates the list with each list item containing the ticket information I want displayed.

How do I select only the data for the ticket when I press its button to populate my other panel? For example, the next section on the page might be a button that will build an email to the person in the data: (haven't tested this code, please give me pointers if I'm doing it all wrong.

```
<a href="mailto:{{ ticket.email_address }}?subject={{ ticket.ticket_number }}&body=Hello%20{{ ticket.first_name }}" type="button" class="btn btn-default" title="pre-formatted email">{{ ticket.email_address || "cannot find email address"}}</a>
```

Problem is, I don't know how to tell it which ticket in tickets to reference...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example, hope it will help you

http://plnkr.co/edit/7rAqx9nMBuzhdEAUQpZF?p=preview

You just need to use a reference

```
  $scope.selectedTicket = {};
```

Comment: I got it working!!! I wouldn't have been able to do it without your sample code. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a reference to the selected ticket in your scope. For example:

```
<div ng-controller="QueueCtrl">
    <ul class="list-unstyled" ng-repeat="ticket in tickets">
        <li ng-click="cont.selectedTicket = ticket"><div data-queue-item></div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And then in your panel below:

```
<div class="slected-ticket-info">
    <div>{{cont.selectedTicket.someValue}}</div>
</div>
```

Where `someValue` is just some child key on your ticket object. Or as per your `<a>` example:

```
<a href="mailto:{{ cont.selectedTicket.email_address }}?...
```

Just make sure in your parent controller you create the container variable so the children can reference it:

```
$scope.cont = {};
```

Comment: since 'selectedTicket' is defined within the child scope created by ng-repeat, and since you're setting _selectedTicket_ within it, the selectedTicket scope variable will not resolve correctly (each ng-repeat will get its own copy of selectedTicket). But, if you introduce a '.' in the model, it should work.  i.e. ng-click="$parent.selectedTicket = ticket"

Comment: You're right, however your fix doesn't seem to be fixing it. I've tried your code "$parent.selectedTicket = ticket" and the reference $scope.selectedTicket is not changing from {}.